# List executable's nix runtime dependencies?

Tags: nix, nixos

For an executable compiled in NixOS, is the following a good way to find runtime dependencies:

- run `ldd` on the executable, which gives a list of store paths
- run `nix-store --query --references $store_path`

?

(Given that `ldd` doesn't list anything outside of nix store)

Comment: The general assumption Nix makes when calculating dependencies is that any store path it can find as a string anywhere in the content of a built derivation _is in fact a runtime dependency of that item_, which is what `nix-store --query` will give you (when pointed at the output, not the derivation that created it). If you're asking only for _library_ dependencies that's narrower, but we'd need to know more about your use case to understand why you wouldn't just go with nix-store's calculation of your closure.

Comment: I don't what you mean about `ldd` not listing anything outside the Nix store -- there _shouldn't_ be any dependencies outside the Nix store, and if you're building on proper NixOS with the sandbox enabled, that's strictly enforced.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy My use case is for an already compiled executable, i.e I don't have the result store path -- I've been able to build the executable within `nix develop` but haven't yet been able to build it into a result store path (might not be the ideal way to go about it, but this is what I got :)).

Comment: As you say, `ldd` doesn't actually list anything outside of the nix store so that assumption is correct.

Comment: Ah. Assuming you're building a derivation (vs just trying to inject a hand-build binary), I'd probably start with something close to your devshell's full dependency set, then see which of those things turn into actual runtime dependencies and (try to) strip out the rest -- if something breaks you know what to put back.